# Flowplayer 5.3.0 with Mootols 1.4.5 and jQuery 1.9 conflict

Tags: jquery, mootools, flowplayer

I am building a project that I've built using MooTools. There is a lot of videos built into the design and I've decided to migrate from VideoJS to Flowplayer, because of all the great events and customizable look.

Here is how I setup the header:

- Add MooTools

  ```
  <?php Assets::js(array(
      // Libs
      'readme.js',
      'lib/mootools-yui-compressed.js',
      'lib/...',
      'lib/...',
  ));
  ?>
  ```
- Add jQuery

  ```
  <script
      src="<?=base_url();?>/static/js/lib/jquery190.js">
      jQuery.noConflict();
  </script>
  ```
- Add Mootools

  ```
  <script src="<?=base_url();?>static/js/flowplayer530/flowplayer.js"></script>
  ```

This is the setup that actually loads the player and let's me play the video. But still when I look at FireBug, I see this.
(can't post images yet)
"RefferenceError: jQuery is not defined."

```
   slice.call( docElem.childNodes, 0 )[0].nodeType;   ->  jquery190.js (line 3811)
```

My point is, that if jQuery is not defined how should Flowplayer even run?

TLDR; The player works, but I do not like errors like this to happen, and I would like to know why.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: show rendered html, not your php code.

Comment: I would use mootools no-conflict as well if you're going to be using other libraries with mootools